# Mingw-w64 C11 threads.h not found?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use the **C11** standard threading in my program, and I'm using the *Mingw-w64* toolchain `x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0` specifically.

When I `#include <threads.h>` as the **C11** standard defines, I get the `No such file or directory` error from *gcc*. I have found that I can `#include <pthread.h>` without error. I am passing the `-std=c11` argument to `gcc`, btw.

I've searched high and low on the internet for any information about the standard **C** threading support. All I can find information on is for **C++**. Can somebody please explain to me why I can't use the **C11** standard `threads.h` library?

EDIT:
I've also checked if the **STDC_NO_THREADS** macro is defined. It seems to be undefined.

```
#ifdef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
printf("We got no threads capp'n!\n");
#endif
```

I get no message about not having threads.

Comment: `mingw64` builds against `msvcrt` and not `glibc`. Check for the `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` macro and if it's defined.

Comment: It would seem to be UNDEFINED.

Comment: Also, I don't see what msvcrt and glibc have to do with this?

Comment: C11 threads are not very well supported by C compilers or standard libraries. If you want to use them on Windows, look into Pelles C.

Comment: Well that sucks. I wonder why not? Especially since C++ seems to get support without a problem? I guess I have nothing left to do but to go complain or to fix it myself then...

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem on Windows 11. There is no *threads.h* under Mingw-w64 and vs 2022. But if you want to use it you can install Msys2 and gcc on it. After installation you find the head file there! I add *thread.h* into the source file and test it. Of course gcc in Msys2 compiles it with no error and warning. And I finally add *__STDC_NO_THREADS__* and *__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__* into the source and the compiler passes the error that the macros are undeclared. So the compiler support the C11 standard Concurrency support library.